# Codechef rejection (factorial of a number)

Tags: c++, c++17, factorial

Why is codechef rejecting this solution even though it's giving desirable outputs on codechef code runner itself? (Factorial of a number)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    
int t;
cin>>t;
int n;
int fact=1;

for(int i=0; i<t;i++){
    cin>>n;
    for(int i=1; i<=n; i++){
        fact=fact*i;
    }cout<<fact;
    cout<<endl;
    fact=1;
    
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ask your problem to calculate 100 factorial and you will know

Comment: Does the exercise tell you the max valid input?

Comment: @VidorVistrom Yup, it's giving me zero as the answer

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Max input according to question is 100

Answer (score 1):

As you are storing the result of factorial in `int` variable, which has a max limit of `2147483647`, so for numbers larger than this, factorial will not be computed correctly.

Try using other data types which can have max higher limits. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/cpp-integer-limits?view=msvc-160